# Altium 18 - Problem when switching from Schematic to PCB

Tags: pcb, altium

I have a rather odd problem when I switch from Schematic to PCB in Altium 18. 
I go to the PCB file, I press the "Update PCB Document", then all is good, except for some components (test points) which is able to place them on the PCB, but is unable to connect them to nets.

The strange thing is that in both the schematic and the PCB file they are named TP1, TP2, etc, but in the window that appears after I press "Update PCB Document", they are written as TP1-1, TP2-1, etc. and of course I get an error that it cannot find the components (because they do not exist, TP1 exists, TP1-1 does not). Anyone has any idea what is causing this error, did I mess something up or should I contact support?

[image]

Comment: The component is TP1. One of its pads (but usually a test point only has one pad) is TP1-1.

Comment: Does your footprint have a pad numbered "1"?

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot you showed is where Altium is adding pins to nets. The pins have the nomenclature -<pin_no>, so the test point with component with designator TP1 has one pad called "TP1-1".  It is adding that pin to the Net that it belongs to. There is no apparent error in what you have shown, only an error in your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find a solution. 
In case anyone has the same problem, here is how I fixed it:

In the PCB file, click Design->Netlist->Clear all nets... then import changes from schematic. It should now work.

Comment: so you found a solution without actually knowing the root cause.

Comment: … which is much better than no solution at all

Comment: Altium has so many bugs that it is nearly impossible to figure out the root cause for some issues.